# Deleting todos not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When a todo is created,I push it onto this array:

```
$scope.$on('todo:created',function(event,todo){
    $scope.model.todos.push(todo);
});
```

I am trying to delete a todo using the `$scope.$on` functionality like this:

```
//from a child scope for the item
$scope.actions.remove = function remove()
{
    TodoService.delete($scope.model.todo);
    $scope.$emit('todo:deleted',$scope.model.todo);
};

//from a parent of the scope which has ng-repeat:

$scope.$on('todo:deleted',function(event,todo){
    for(var i =0;i<$scope.model.todos.length;i++)
    {
        if(todo._id === $scope.model.todos[i]._id)
        {
            console.log(i);
            $scope.model.todos.splice(i,1);
            break;
        }

    }
});
```

I find that this seemingly normal code causes a lot of issues:

```
1)last item gets deleted correctly
2)when deleting the penultimate item,the last item gets deleted
3)all other items are unresponsive on delete
```

I find that the UI renders with the correct items deleted on page reload.

I have tried changing the code to:

```
$scope.$on('todo:deleted',function(event,todo){
                 $scope.model.todos = $.grep($scope.model.todos, function (todoItem, i) {
                      if (todoItem._id === todo._id) {
                        console.log(i);
                        return false;
                      } else {
                        return true;
                      }
                    });
            });
```

The entire code can be found [here on github](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/angular-jspm-todo)

EDIT:

My code uses `ng-repeat` like this:

```
 <section class="ui three column doubling page grid">
   <div class="column" ng-repeat="todo in model.todos track by $index">
      <todo-item value="todo"></todo-item>
   </div>
</section>
```

## UPDATE:

I have tried to accomplish the delete using this code:

```
  var onItemDeleted = function onItemDeleted(todo){
                var todos = $scope.model.todos;
                var checkIndex = function checkIndex(t){
                    return t._id !== todo._id;
                };
                todos = todos.filter(checkIndex);
                //$scope.model.todos = todos;
            };

            $scope.$on('todo:deleted',function(event,todo){
                $scope.$apply(onItemDeleted(todo));
            });

            var onTodoAdded = function onTodoAdded(todo){
                var todos = $scope.model.todos;
                todos.push(todo);
            };

            $scope.$on('todo:created',function(event,todo){
                $scope.$apply(onTodoAdded(todo));
            });
```

In both these cases,I get the error:

Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:66)
    at beginPhase (angular.js:14823)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14567)
    at app.js:218
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$emit (angular.js:14715)
    at app.js:264
    at processQueue (angular.js:13251)
    at angular.js:13267
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14469)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14285)

I have tried replacing the data by replacing the data from the service like this:

```
  $scope.$on('todo:deleted',function(event,todo){
                var todosPromise = TodoService.get();
                todosPromise.then(function(data){
                    $scope.model.todos = data;
                });
            });
```

And I have changed the event code to fire only after the delete operation is completed:

```
 $scope.actions.remove = function remove(id)
        {
            TodoService.deleteItem($scope.model.todo)
            .then(function(){
                $scope.$emit('todo:deleted',$scope.model.todo);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err,err.stack);
            });

        };
```

I find that the data from the service or upon splicing is obtained correctly but the wrong element is pulled by `ng-repeat`,is it because I am using `track by $index`.

Comment: Try renaming your delete function to deleteItem or something similar, 'delete' is a reserved word in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I faced some issues with `splice` and used `$grep` to fix those issues.

Can you try the below code:

```
$scope.$on('todo:deleted',function(event, todo) {    
    $scope.model.todos = $.grep($scope.model.todos, function (todoItem, i) {
      if (todoItem._id === todo._id) {
        return false;
        console.log(i);
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried the approach,$.grep is selecting the correct value for `i` but it is still doing a bad remove operation.